# Bind Lion Client to a Leopard Server

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, osx-leopard, osx-server

Trying to bind a **Lion** Client (10.7.1) to a **Leopard** Server (10.5.8). Getting a `connection failed to the directory server. (2100)` error after they appear to talk for a few seconds!?!

Can Lion bind to Leopard? **I** haven't read that it can't.

Comment: If 10.5 and 10.7 *were* incompatible, Apple would quickly be eaten by angry customers. (Microsoft still has to keep AD somewhat compatible with MS-DOS...)

Comment: ok. that's what I thought. but I can't make 'em play nice! Problem probably on our end then…

Comment: still can't make it work!

Comment: Have you attempted to load a lion open directory schema into the Snow Leopard directory server? It could be as simple as making schema changes. I wouldn't be surprised that Apple isn't providing a neat script to upgrade things, but LDAP is LDAP and a port is a port - so you should be able to whip your Leopard directory into shape with enough time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple says to update Lion to 10.7.2 to fix this problem](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3958). It didn't work for me though.